# Update the content of a page using jquery ajax call to a struts action

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am displaying a chart on a jsp page by reading the contents from database. I want to change the chart data based on the items selected from a checkboxlist on the page using ajax.

The script is as below

```
$('[name="overlay"]').click(function() {
        var checkeditems = new Array();
        var boxes = $('input[name=overlay]:checked');
        $(boxes).each(function(){
            checkeditems.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "getOperation.action",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: "checkeditems=" + checkeditems,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error ' + textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data){ 
                ('#totalbox').html(data);
               }
        });


      });
```

Here on clicking any checkbox in the checkboxlist (`name=overlay`), I am passing the list of selected items to the struts action.

I am able to access the `checkeditems` in my action class and based on them, I read the data from the database and change the hashmap used to display the data on the chart. (Printing the content of the hashmap on console gives the correct data.)

But I am confused how to update the data in the chart on the page. The chart gets updated only on page refresh.

Since the data returned by success is html, I tried using the html(data) on the `totalbox` div which is the parent div for chart.

Can someone please help me in figuring out how to update the page content.

Comment: what's the value of your "data" on success? also, you're missing a $ sign before the "totalbox" selector...

Comment: Show the HTML used to display the chart

Comment: @Th0rndike.. Thanks adding the $ sign fixed it. I completely overlooked the syntax error :P